# Orientation on power unlock iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, orientation

I set my application orientation to landscape in info_plist, but when i lock my iphone and unlock it for a second my application turns to portrait mode and come back again to landscape.

this is happening only on iphone 5s and iphone 5, means a small size screen as it works fine for all other devices.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add the following code in `AppDelegate.cs`

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
}
```

Comment: did not work for me, i debug it it goes to this method on unlock of device but for a second it still turns to portrait.

Comment: Did you set the Device Orientation in info.plist? Uncheck ' Portrait '.

Comment: yes portrait is unchecked, thatz why i am surprise like why still it turns to portrait for a second.